# saving python variable to csv

Tags: python, csv, variables

i am having troubles on this python error.
I want to save changing variables to an csv file, however while the code runs again with an different variable it overwrites the previous one. I do not have the variables predetermined, they are generated while the code runs, so every time the loop will loop the program there will a different email passed.

Here is my code:

```
import csv

def hello(hme):
        header = ['email']
        data = [hme]


        with open('countries.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)


                writer.writerow(header)
                writer.writerows(data)

hello(["test@icloud.com"])
```

Thank you!

Comment: Probably easier to use pandas data frame and then covert to csv through  `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`

Comment: if you don't want to overwrite the existing value open the file in append mode

Comment: @VRComp Bringing in a `pandas` dependency seems quite overkill for this simple task…

Comment: @NicolasMoreau Good point. I was thinking maybe OP will expand the code to include more rows, which is why I suggested `pandas`. This could be a simple case and OP wanted to apply it to a larger case later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should open the file as append, instead of write:
'a' instead of 'w'

```py
import csv

def hello(hme):
        header = ['email']
        data = [hme]


        with open('countries.csv', 'a', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)


                writer.writerow(header)
                writer.writerows(data)

hello(["test@icloud.com"])
```

Comment: hi thanks for the response, if i write emails manually and delete `writer.writerow(header)` and  `header = ['email']` it outputs like this `emailtest@icloud.com` and if i keep the header it outputs `email #new row email #new row test@icloud.com`

Comment: however if i manually type `email #new row` it just works fine

Answer (score 0):

Just replace 'w' by 'a' where 'w' writes in file (override) while 'a' appends the file whenever you write in it.

```
with open('countries.csv', 'a', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
```

For the header "email" just write it before you add the loop of emails to do not duplicate it

Answer (score 0):

Read the file contents first; add the new data; write the data to a file.

```
def hello(hme):
    try:
        with open('countries.csv', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
            stuff = list(csv.reader(f))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # this must be the first time the function was called
        stuff = [['email']]
    stuff.append([hme])

    with open('countries.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(stuff)
```

---

If your file really only has one *column* you don't really need to use the csv module. Just append the new line to the file.

```
# assumes header is present
def hello(hme):
    with open('countries.csv', 'a', encoding='UTF8') as f:
        f.write(hme + '\n')
```